# Esp8266 HttpClient Post

Tags: http-post, httpclient, arduino-esp8266

I am trying to create a call to a server on the web making use of HttpPost but i keep getting a response of -1 (error: connection refused)

I am able to make an HTTPGet request but my httpPost fails. If i take that same data that i am trying to post and put that into Fiddler and do a post from there i get a 200 OK.

Below is the code that i am trying to execute :

```
void PostData() {
  String data = "mailSend=1&new=1&rec=Gupta+Classic&topic=ddd&reply=ddd&fbSig=bE9";
  String url = "https://www.shippingmanager.dk/sh/mailbox.php";
  HTTPClient http;
  http.setReuse(true);
  http.begin(url);
  http.addHeader("Host", "www.shippingmanager.dk");
  http.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0");
  http.addHeader("Accept-Language", " en-US,en;q=0.5");
  http.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", " gzip, deflate, br");
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", " application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
  http.addHeader("X-Requested-With", " XMLHttpRequest");
  http.addHeader("Referer", " https://www.shippingmanager.dk/sh/?fb_source=shippingmanager.dk");
  http.addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
  http.addHeader("Pragma", " no-cache");
  http.addHeader("Cache-Control", " no-cache");

  int result = http.POST(data);
  http.writeToStream(&Serial);
  http.end();

}
```

this is the raw text that i post in Fiddler to do the post :

```
POST https://www.shippingmanager.dk/sh/mailbox.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.shippingmanager.dk
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0 
Accept: */* 
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest 
Referer: https://www.shippingmanager.dk/sh/?fb_source=shippingmanager.dk  
Connection: keep-alive 
Pragma: no-cache 
Cache-Control: no-cache

mailSend=1&new=1&rec=Gupta+Classic&topic=ddd&reply=ddd&fbSig=J9
```

Please can someone point me to my problem.

I also tried the code in this link and that also failed me :-(

http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=14054

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is the "https" protocol you're using. I guess there is a different code for "https", so try again replacing the "https" in the url by "http".